# Need Help: VS code auto complete is not working in React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I need help. VS code autocomplete is not working I have tried everything but still the same problem. On "ctrl+space" it shows "loading..."

here is me vs code settings:

I am using .jsx extension and I tried "*.jsx" but not working.

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Operator Mono Lig, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "editor.fontSize": 20,
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
    "typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePage",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
      "javascript": "javascriptreact",
     },
     "files.associations": {
       "*.js": "javascriptreact"
      },
     "workbench.colorTheme": "Mirage (High-contrast)"
}
```

Comment: try downgrading the version of VS code, and check

Comment: Thanks, It worked but why they released with this bug.

Comment: You should file an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose

Comment: @Mohitmohit , i thought may be the issue is with my system or some thing , i was not sure that this was a bug, did not care to report it